# #unique not summing up correctly based on order of events

Tags: complex-event-processing, esper

As answered in [Esper sum of snapshots (as opposed to sum of deltas)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73495477/esper-sum-of-snapshots-as-opposed-to-sum-of-deltas), `#unique(field)` ensures that the sum is using specified field when summing up the values. That worked great except in the case listed below.

Given the following epl:

```
create schema StockTick(security string, price double);
create schema OrderEvent (orderId int, trader string, symbol string, strategy string, 
quantity double);

select orderId, trader, symbol, strategy, sum(quantity) 
from OrderEvent#unique(orderId) as o
full outer join StockTick#lastevent as t 
on o.symbol = t.security
group by trader, symbol, strategy
```

The following events:

```
StockTick={security='IBM', price=99}
OrderEvent={orderID=1, trader="A", symbol='IBM', strategy="VWAP", quantity=10}
StockTick={security='IBM', price=99}
```

correctly provides the sum as `sum(quantity)=10.0`.

But if the `StockTick` did not happen first:

```
OrderEvent={orderID=1, trader="A", symbol='IBM', strategy="VWAP", quantity=10}
StockTick={security='IBM', price=99}
```

I *still* expected the value of quantity to be 10. But in this case it is `sum(quantity)=20.0`!!

Based on that `#unique(field)` does, I figure this shouldn’t be 20. Why is `#unique(field)` not being adhered to and what is needed in the query for the output to be unique on `orderId` for both cases?

The following set of events is also available to run on Esper Notebook
https://notebook.esperonline.net/#/notebook/2HE9662E6

Answer (score 0):

In a streaming join the aggregation result aggregates all rows produced by the join. Since the join produces 2 rows as output with quantity 10 each the result is 20.

You can take an aggregation of the result of the join and unique by order id, you can use insert into. Like so:

```
insert into JoinedStream select orderId, trader, symbol, strategy, quantity
from OrderEvent#unique(orderId) as o
full outer join StockTick#lastevent as t 
on o.symbol = t.security;

select orderId, trader, symbol, strategy, sum(quantity) 
from JoinedStream#unique(orderId)
group by trader, symbol, strategy;
```

Comment: But isn’t that the whole point of `#unique`? For example, if I put on multiple `OrderEvents` with the same `orderId`, `sum` adheres to the uniqueness and sums up to 10. Even if I add 100 `OrderEvents` will only get 10.

Comment: In addition ... the “second” event only happens if `StockTick` wasn’t sent before the `OrderEvent`

Comment: Maybe you are looking for the "unidirectional" keytword